# django update form with materialize modal

Tags: jquery, django, materialize

I have this code in my django project and I am trying to edit records with a materialize modal, but it always returns a url with id 1 "cpemodels/edit/1/" and so I can only edit the record with the id 1, I have a table with edit button in every row. (i dont have any issues when edit record with external page).

urls.py

```
   path('cpemodel/edit/<int:pk>/', cpemodel_edit, name='cpemodel_edit')
```

views.py

```
def cpemodel_edit(request, pk=None):
cmodel = get_object_or_404(CPEMODEL, pk=pk)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CPEMODELForm(request.POST, instance=cmodel)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('cpemodel')
else:
    form = CPEMODELForm(instance=cmodel)

return render(request,'provision/cpemodel/edit.html',{'form': form, 'cmodel': cmodel })
```

cpemodel.html

```
<table class="responsive-table striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Modelo</th>
    <th>Descripción</th>
    <th>Vendor</th>
    <th>Tipo</th>
    <th>ETHs</th>
    <th>POTs</th>
    <th>TV</th>
    <th>WIFI</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
```

{% for cpemodel in object_list %}

```
<tr>
    <td>{{cpemodel.model}}</td>
    <td>{{cpemodel.desc}}</td>
    <td>{{cpemodel.vendor}}</td>
    <td>{{cpemodel.type}}</td>
    <td>{{cpemodel.eth_ports}}</td>
    <td>{{cpemodel.pot_ports}}</td>
    <td>{{cpemodel.catv_port}}</td>
    <td>{{cpemodel.wifi}}</td>

    <td><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light green light-3 hoverable" href="{% url 'cpemodel_edit' cpemodel.id %}"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
    <td><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red light-3 hoverable" href="{% url 'cpemodel_delete' cpemodel.id %}"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></td>

    <td><button class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" data-source="cpemodel/edit/{{cpemodel.id}}/"  href="#modal1">Modal</button></td>

    <div id="modal1" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
```

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.modal').modal(); 
$('.modal-trigger').click(function(){ 
var url = $('.modal-trigger').attr("data-source");
// use other ajax submission type for post, put ...
$.get( url, function( data ) {
    // use this method you need to handle the response from the view 
    // with rails Server-Generated JavaScript Responses this is portion will be in a .js.erb file  
    $( ".modal-content" ).html(data);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

i just solved, noticed that .modal-trigger function always took first .modal-trigger.

```
<td><button class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" onclick="edit('{% url 'cpemodel_edit' cpemodel.id %}')">Editar</button></td>
  function edit(url){ 
 $('.modal-content').load (url, function() {
  $('.modal').modal(); 
  $('#modal1').modal('open');
});
```

};